# Getting the value from key in a dictionary that is nearest to a given number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I have a dictionary (keys are integers, values are float). I would now ask the dictionary for the value of the key that is > than the given number but < than the next greater key.

Example:

dict = {100: 0.0035, 150: 0.0024, 200: 0.0019}.

i give 122, it should give me 0.0035

i give 333, it should give me 0.0019

i give 200, it should give me 0.0024

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, 200 is greater than the key 150 but not less than the key 200 so which value should be retrieved for 200?

Comment: If i give the number 200 the result should be 0.0024, when I give the number 201 the result should be 0.0019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example (tested under Firefox 3.6):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dict = {100: 0.0035, 150: 0.0024, 200: 0.0019};

function r(aNum) {
    var result;

    for (var key in dict) {
        var dist = key - aNum

        if ((dist < 0 && dist < result) || result === undefined) {
            result = key;
        }
    }

    return dict[result];
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('n', '')
        $(this).html(id + ": " + r(id));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="n122"></li>
        <li id="n333"></li>
        <li id="n200"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By `$(this).html(id + ": " + s(id));` you probably mean `$(this).html(id + ": " + r(id));`

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case for a binary tree. The topic is a little broad for a stack overflow answer, but here goes anyway.

```
function addValueToNode(tree, nodeidx, value) {
    var left = 2*nodeidx + 1;
    var right = 2*nodeidx + 2;

    if(value > tree[nodeidx]) {
        if(!tree[right])
            tree[right] = value;
        else
            addValueToNode(tree, right, value);
    } else {
        if(!tree[left])
            tree[left] = value;
        else
            addValueToNode(tree, left, value);
    }
}

function addValueToTree(tree, value) {
    if(tree.length == 0)
        tree.push(value)
    else
        addValueToNode(tree, 0, value);
}

function addValuesToTree(tree, values) {
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        addValueToTree(tree, values[i]);
}

function addDictionaryToTree(tree, dict) {
    var values = [];
    for(var key in dict) {
        values.push(key);
    }
    values.sort();
    addValuesToTree(tree, values);
}

function findClosestValue(tree, nodeidx, value) {
    var left = 2*nodeidx + 1;
    var right = 2*nodeidx + 2;

    if(value > tree[nodeidx]) {
        if(!tree[right] || tree[right] == value)
            return tree[nodeidx];
        else
            return findClosestValue(tree, right, value);
    } else {
        if(!tree[left])
            return tree[nodeidx];
        else
            return findClosestValue(tree, left, value);
    }
}
var tree = [];
var dict = {100: 0.0035, 150: 0.0024, 200: 0.0019};

addDictionaryToTree(tree, dict);

var closest = findClosestValue(tree, 0, 175);
var dictValue = dict[closest];

alert( closest + " : " + dictValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 122;
var min = null;
var minkey = null;
for ( var key : dict ) {
  if (min==null || abs(value-key)<min) {
      min=abs(value-key);
      minkey = key;
  }
}
return dict[minkey]
```

You can try this. Sorry if smth, i have no chance to test it.

Comment: By `var key : dict` you probably mean `var key in dict` ... other than that, it should do the trick.

Comment: doesn't work: outputs 122>0.0035, 333>0.0019, 200>0.0019
Note abs should be Math.abs

Answer (score 0):

The following function matchs your requirements:

```
function getNumber(dict, value) {
  var key, found;

  for (key in dict) {
    if (value - key > 0) {
      found = key;
    }
  }
  return dict[found];
}

var dict = {100: 0.0035, 150: 0.0024, 200: 0.0019};

// Firebug assertions
console.assert(getNumber(dict, 122) == 0.0035);
console.assert(getNumber(dict, 333) == 0.0019);
console.assert(getNumber(dict, 200) == 0.0024);
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary search, using a modified (stable) algorithm that searches for the least element meeting the comparison criteria.

Answer (score -1):

If your dictionary is not huge, you could try to cycle from, for example, (122-1). If it's undefined, subtract 1 and try again, until you find something :)